# Using Averaging and Deck Transformations to Compute de Rham Cohomologies of the $n$-Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, covering-spaces

I'm preparing for some comprehensive exams and this is a question from a past year.

> The $n$-torus $T^n = \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is both a smooth n-manifold and an Abelian group, by virtue of structures inherited from the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, $T^n$ acts on itself by smooth maps corresponding to translations of $\mathbb{R}^n$. By averaging, prove that each de Rham cohomology class on $T^n$ contains a unique differential form which is translation-invariant. Then use this observation to calculate the dimensions of the de Rham cohomology vector spaces $H^p(T^n)$ for all $p$.

I can compute the de Rham cohomology using Kunneth's formula and some induction (I think the dimensions are something like $n \choose p$) but that isn't the point. Plus, I'm quite curious about this idea of averaging so that we get something invariant under group actions. I've seen a similar question on showing that a Lens space is orientable by looking at some averaged form and then showing it is invariant under some orientation preserving transformations, or something like that.

Comment: Here's a link that addresses your question: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/the-cohomology-of-the-n-torus/ It gives several methods for computing the cohomology and method 3 is relevant for you.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Unfortunately, I have almost zero idea of what is going on, such as this result about Lie groups and Haar measures.